# Wake up a blocking redis call inside a signal handler in python

Tags: python, redis, signals, redis-py

I need to wake up a blocked pop (redis client) on a list thru a signal handling (in this case SIGUSR1)

This is the sample code:

```
import redis
import signal

r = redis.Redis()

def handler(signal, frame):
    q = redis.Redis()
    q.rpush('test', 1)
    print 'sign arrived'

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)

print 'start'
print r.blpop('asd')
print 'end'
```

the output of this code is

```
start
// here I send the signal with "$ kill -10 <pid>"
sign arrived
```

and stop

other informations:

- the result of the push inside the handler is 1 (it should mean that an element have actually been inserted in the list)
- if I open a parallel redis-cli shell, no element is shown with "LRANGE" even after the signal handling
- redis-cli command "CLIENT LIST" shows the blpop client

What is wrong?
thanks in advance

---

#### update

if I duplicate the push, works:

```
def handler(signal, frame):
    q = redis.Redis()
    q.rpush('test', 1)
    q.rpush('test', 1)
    print 'sign arrived'
```

And no other message seems last in the redis queue.
It looks like the first push disappears...

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Did you ever work out why this happens?